# Getting a UITapGestureRecognizers Target

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to create a basic view, whose `backgroundColor` is toggled between two colors each time it is tapped. To achieve this I created a function that takes as arguments the view to be changed and the two colors to toggle between.

For this to work I need to pass the UIView that it should then change. But UIViews can't natively recognize touches so I "linked" (I am unsure I understood this right) a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it that triggers an action in my `ViewController`.

**Now I need to get the UITapGestures linked `UIView` so I can change it.**

I realize I could simple enter the corresponding UIView into the action, but I want to make this function as flexible as possible (just trying to start out with the right etiquette).

Here is my imcomplete function:

```
@IBAction func colorViewTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("tap")
    //Heres the problem: I get an "Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'UIView'
    toggleViewBackgroundColor(view: sender, color1: UIColor.blue, color2: UIColor.brown)
}
```

Comment: you can cast  `sender` into `UITapGestureRecognizer`  than use its .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your action method argument type to `UITapGestureRecognizer` from `Any` and then use [`view`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624212-view) property of `UIGestureRecognizer` to get the reference of tapped view.

```
@IBAction func colorViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap")
    toggleViewBackgroundColor(view: sender.view!, color1: UIColor.blue, color2: UIColor.brown)
}
```

Comment: .view is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you so much!